Why is my SSH terminal sluggish (slow) when typing commands?
I have a new Raspberry Pi. When I burned my SD card, I followed the recommendations given in the Raspberry Pi Imager and installed the 'bullseye' version of the OS. I have made no configuration changes to my system since installing it. Everything seems to work OK, but I have noticed there is a significant amount of "lag" or "latency" when I am typing commands into the SSH terminal on my PC.
When I enter a command from the SSH terminal, I do not see an immediate "echo" of what I am typing in my terminal for sometimes several seconds. If I pause typing, it usually "catches up", but not always. I've gotten a few buggered commands (I'm not a "touch" typist) that create some chaos.
I don't see this "lag" when using an attached keyboard/mouse/monitor. I have checked my WiFi, and found no issues... it works flawlessly on all other hosts - except for the RPis.
I have tried changing SSH client hosts (from one PC to another). I have researched the SSH client and server configurations, hoping to find a setting that would alleviate this issue. And I have re-installed the OS several times now trying to isolate it to 'bullseye' vs 'bookworm' or '32-bit' vs '64-bit'. None of this has resulted in any relief from the "laggy" SSH terminal. The problem does seem to be worse on my "RPi Zero 2W" as compared to my "RPi 4B" machine, but the lag problem exists to a greater or lesser degree on both.
QUESTION: What is causing this "laggy" SSH terminal behavior, and how do I "fix" it?

You can try running a continuous ping from your SSH client to the Raspberry Pi to see if there are any intermittent spikes in latency or dropped packets. You can use a command like ping -t <RaspberryPi_IP> on Windows or ping <RaspberryPi_IP> on Linux/macOS to do this.

It "sounds like" you may be suffering from a misguided bureaucratic effort to save energy/power at the expense of normally performant WiFi. I've not been able to trace this to its ultimate source, but it may be related to an "initiative" authored by the "WiFi Alliance" to save energy by turning WiFi OFF when it's perceived to be "not needed". The WiFi Alliance's blurb mentions battery conservation as a motivator, but that doesn't explain how it came to be the default setting in devices (RPi for example) that draw their power from a mains source. More likely this is another example of incompetence and/or "climate politics" at some level in the "software delivery chain"; i.e. a "mis-application of technology" if you prefer a more PC view of things.
You can check to determine the status of WiFi power save on your machine(s):
$ iw wlan0 get power_save 

# you'll get one of two responses:
Power save: on

# --OR--

Power save: off

If you find it on, the cure is easy (for now at least). There are (at least) two choices for disabling the "WiFi Power Save" :
1. via cron; using the root crontab:
sudo crontab -e 

# add one line: 

@reboot /usr/sbin/iw wlan0 set power_save off > /home/pi/wifipowersave.log 2>&1 

# save & close editor

2. via nmcli; Network Manager's command line tool:
sudo nmcli con mod preconfigured wifi.powersave disable

Note that this works only for the preconfigured connection profile; if you create other profiles, you will need to apply it there as well.
One of those should do it - it worked in my case.

Recently I have noticed annoying pauses using ssh, but as my Mac & Pi4 are both connected by Ethernet to the same Gigabit switch I doubt WiFi is the culprit.

Are you using usb to power your pi ? because this lag I faced in pi zero 2w is because of power and when I am running a process the cpu frequency reach maximum set frequency,
So here you can try these ,

use power adapter if you are using usb
set minimum freq & maximum freq at 700Mhz in /boot/firmware/config.txt

